How can I reattach the hinges on my bathroom vanity cabinet?
Is there a relatively easy way to fix these vanity sink doors?


The hinge looks rusty. The rust probably made the hinge stiffer than a normal working hinge. This is why it pulled out of the door.
You should get a new pair of hinges. (upper and lower) and use longer screws as others noted. However screws that are too long can stick through the front of the door, creating another issue.
I would get a hinge mending plate with the new set of hinges.

You have a few options.

Drill new holes for appropriate screws alongside the original holes. You don't necessarily need flathead screws which are countersunk. A pan-head screw on the surface is fine. Key is good penetration into the door without bulging the face. This requires precise piloting.

Epoxy. Just glue the hinge body into the recess. You'll fill the recess completely and set the hinge into it (after cleaning up the hinge). You could also use epoxy in the original screw holes with the original screws for additional hold.



Though for ease of repair, I'd highly suggest removing the hinges from the cabinet body, so you're only working with the hinges on the door itself, not while it's hung on the cabinet.  Then once your fix is complete, you can reattach the hinges to the cabinet itself.

Not a bad idea, but you need to be sure everything's aligned well. That might be difficult with it disassembled. I might try a clamp with it still attached.
